# drop-down values referenced from another drop-down value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, html-select

I am making a bookings page for a movie theater. I would like the user to be able to choose days in which movies are showing and then based off the day, the sessions that are available.

For example, the first drop-down menu displays movies currently showing. if someone wants to see Pixels, then the second drop down menu displays the days Pixels is showing. Once the user selects a day, then the third drop down menu will provide the times that Pixels is showing on that particular day.

```
    <label>Movie Name:
                                <select id="movie" name="movie">
                                    <option selected="selected" value="">Please select a movie</option>
                                    <option value="Pixels">Pixels</option>
                                    <option value="Straight_Outta_Compton">Straight Outta Compton</option>
                                    <option value="Last_Cab_To_Darwin">Last Cab To Darwin</option>
                                    <option value="Nicki_and_The_Flash">Nicki and The Flash</option>
                                    </option>
                                </select>
                            </label>

                            </br>

                            <label>Session Day:
                                <select id="day" name="day">
                                        <option selected="selected" value="">Please select...</option>
                                        <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
                                        <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
                                        <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
                                        <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
                                        <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
                                        <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
                                        <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
                                </select>
                            </label>

                            </br>

                            <label>Session Time:
                                <select id="time" name="time">
                                        <option selected="selected" value="">Please select...</option>
                                        <option value="1200">12:00</option>
                                        <option value="1300">13:00</option>
                                        <option value="1500">15:00</option>
                                        <option value="1800">18:00</option>
                                        <option value="2100">21:00</option>
                                </select>
                            </label>
```

Lets say Pixels shows on Mondays and Tuesdays and the only times it shows is at 13:00 and 18:00. How would i write the jQuery to provide this sort of functionality?

Comment: It is hard to inspect flat code, adding jsfiddle || plnkr || codepen gives you style, strength and more answers.

Comment: if i use jsfiddle, do i need all the code in my html file, or just the code i have here?

Comment: You need to put in all of the needed code for the problem you're having

Comment: Setup your fiddle in such way it has less as possible code (easy to understand) and everybody could see your problem (reproducible).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/danielb13/jkgm14gr/

i hope that works. Images aren't there but they are irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick exemple on how you can handle this :

---

JS

```
$("#movie").on("change", function(){
    $("#day option, #time option").hide();
    var days = $("option:selected", this).attr("data-days").split(",");
    var times = $("option:selected", this).attr("data-times").split(",");
    for(i=0; i<days.length; i++){
        $("#day option[value="+days[i]+"]").show();
    }
    for(i=0; i<times.length; i++){
        $("#time option[value="+times[i]+"]").show();
    }
});
```

CSS

```
#day option, #time option{
    display:none;
}
```

---

You have to store all informations about each movie in `data-days` and `data-times` attribute.

This way, once selected, you can retrieve all this informations, split them, and display corresponding `<option>`

---

Be carreful, you have a useless `</option>` tag at the end of your "#movie" `<select></select>`

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ajmjux7e/)

---

Edit 1:
From your comment, the solution I can provide could look like [this exemple](https://jsfiddle.net/7oqymezn/)

First, store all info in a `data-` attribute, like `day1[time1,time2];day2[time1,time2]` and so one.

After some `split()` & `substring()` on `#movie` `.change()` event, you can dynamically add specific options for the `#day` select tag (which will now look like `<option value="Monday" data-times="13:00,18:00">Monday</option>`).

Same as before, just make a function that will handle the `data-times` on `#day` `.change()` event to dynamically create the desired `#time` options

Comment: oh wow, i've never seen the data-x attribute before. This is excellent!

Comment: If i wanted to add Thursday and Saturday at 16:00 and 20:00 what would be required? two more variables with two more for loops? (jQuery)

Comment: In this case, it have to be a bit more complex. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: My pleasure, glad it helped :)